# Switching icons on a v-expansion-panel-header upon opening it

Tags: c#, vuetify.js

Trying to fake a radio button effect by switching between two icons and the v-expansion-panel

so far i have replaced the expansion icon with a custom one.. but how can i programmatically switch the icons whenever i click the expansion header?

```
<v-expansion-panel>
   <v-expansion-panel-header>
     <template v-slot:actions>
        <l-icon color="primary">
          radio-on
        </l-icon>
     </template>
       {{ data.text}}
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is a better option than just replacing icons

```
<v-radio-group v-model="selectedItem">
              <v-expansion-panels left>
                <v-expansion-panel>
                  <v-expansion-panel-header hide-actions>
                    <v-radio value="1" label="First"></v-radio>
                  </v-expansion-panel-header>
                  <v-expansion-panel-content />
                </v-expansion-panel>
                <v-expansion-panel>
                  <v-expansion-panel-header hide-actions>
                    <v-radio value="2" label="Second"></v-radio>
                  </v-expansion-panel-header>
                  <v-expansion-panel-content />
                </v-expansion-panel>
              </v-expansion-panels>
            </v-radio-group>
```